# ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U19'), dtype('int64')) -> None

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dtype

I am trying to read csv using pandas. While doing so I am getting this error below:
"ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U19'), dtype('int64')) -> None"
Can someone please explain why am I getting this and what does it mean? Thanks.

```
try:
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    print (now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : Reading data from the File now.")
    file_to_upload = pd.read_csv('D:/data/Desk/de-project/users.csv', delimiter=',')
    df_short = file_to_upload.head()
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    print(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + df_short)
except Exception as e:
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    print(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + ' : Error getting file: ' +  str(e))
```

Comment: please share the full traceback

Comment: Hi @thebjorn thanks for the comment. I have figured out the issue. You can check the answer and I am open if you feel a better approach to share.

Comment: The problem is that anyone could have told you what the problem was immediately if you had printed the traceback (ie. remove the exception handling and let the code fail). The traceback contains vital information for diagnosing such problems and providing it in "I get an error" type questions will get you much more help much more quickly.

Comment: @thebjorn thanks this is a learning for me. I will make sure to do it that way next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out. The issue was with the print function:

```
print(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + df_short)
```

In this the '+' operator was causing the issue as I was tring to print the timestamp and the df. Which is illogical as you cant add a timestamp value with the df.

On way to do it as:

```
print(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + 'Printing df')
print(df_short)
```

Comment: you could just do `print(now.strftime("..."), df_short)`  (comma instead of plus)